# How to avoid copying documents using mongodb Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I need to check info that will be added to database using [Java driver 3.4+](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/) and avoid copies.
In my case, documents will be like:

```
{
  title: "Household Portable Steam Brush Mini Iron Handheld Ironing Machine"
  url: "https://..."
  img: "..."
  price: "..."
}
```

Supposed that each document will be unique. So, I tried to wrote using FindIterable simply like:

```
long found = collection.count(Document.parse(title));
FindIterable<Document> iterable = database.getCollection("rss_feed").find(new Document("title", title)
            .append("url", url)
            .append("img", img)
            .append("price", price));
// check if feed not exists
if (found == 0) {
    Document doc = new Document("title", title)
            .append("url", url)
            .append("img", img)
            .append("price", price);
    collection.insertOne(doc);
    mongoClient.close();

    System.out.println("Feed not exists in database. Written.");
    // to check existing feed and add new feed
} else if (iterable.equals(found)) { // error
    Document doc = new Document("title", title)
            .append("url", url)
            .append("img", img)
            .append("price", price);
    collection.insertOne(doc);
    mongoClient.close();
    // if feed exists
} else {
    System.out.println("Feed exists in database.");
    mongoClient.close();
}
```

In this case I'm getting an error:
[image]

Also tried to create [hash-index](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/indexes/) and check via it:

```
 long found = collection.count(Document.parse(title));
 String indexField  = database.getCollection("rss_feed").createIndex(Indexes.hashed("_id"));

        // check if feed not exists
        if (found == 0) {
            Document doc = new Document("title", title)
                    .append("url", url)
                    .append("img", img)
                    .append("price", price);
            collection.insertOne(doc);
            mongoClient.close();

            System.out.println("Feed not exists in database. Written.");
            // added new feed
        } else if (indexField.equals(found)) { // error
            Document doc = new Document("title", title)
                    .append("url", url)
                    .append("img", img)
                    .append("price", price);
            collection.insertOne(doc);
            mongoClient.close();
            // if feed exists
        } else {
            System.out.println("Feed exists in database.");
            mongoClient.close();
        }
```

Also getting:

[image]

Does anyone know how to realize check if documents with fields is unique in Java? Or what is better to use? I appreciate any help.

Comment: If you have unique fields how can you insert again in elseif condition ? Did you intend to duplicate data when document exist ? What is your use case ?

Comment: @Veeram, I can't understand how to realize check correctly in elseif condition. I supposed that index would be helpful

Comment: It looks like you want to insert when the document with field combination is not found. Something like `Document found = database.getCollection("rss_feed").find(fields).first();
            if (found == null) {
                collection.insertOne(fields);
                mongoClient.close();
                System.out.println("Feed not exists in database. Written.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Feed exists in database.");
                mongoClient.close();
            }`

Comment: @Veeram, I have parser that everyday will check new posts on  website and then check which posts exists and no in db. If already exists posts will add in db just new, because also in db will be older posts.

Comment: That is exactly what I mean as well. Did you intend to update old post ? Please try my  code and let me know.

Comment: @Veeram yes or simply adding new without deleting older, because mongo cloud cluster will check memory and delete without me, as I understand.

Comment: @Veeram, THANK you a lot. It's work for me. I will upvote u, if u write this code as full answer. Tell me, please, this code check document as unique? Can I update my posts similar to this variant?

Comment: @Veeram, I appreciate your help. Can you help me with checking updates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51877204/how-can-i-update-older-documents-using-mongodb-java-driver)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Veeram, I can realize check unique documents using

> insert when the document with field combination is not found.

```
 Document found = database.getCollection("rss_feed").find(fields).first();
    if (found == null) { 
    collection.insertOne(fields); 
    mongoClient.close(); 
    System.out.println("Feed not exists in database. Written."); 
    } else { 
    System.out.println("Feed exists in database.");
     mongoClient.close(); 
    }
```