# How can I update older documents using mongodb Java driver?

Tags: java

I'm trying to realize check existing documents in mongoDB, which I need to update then *(it's not duplicates just older documents)* using Java driver 3.4.

My snippet of code is:

```
 // search feed
        Document found = database.getCollection("rss_feed").find(new Document("title", title)
                .append("url", url)
                .append("img", img)
                .append("price", price)).first();
        if (found == null) {
            collection.insertOne(new Document("title", title)
                    .append("url", url)
                    .append("img", img)
                    .append("price", price));
                     mongoClient.close();
        System.out.println("Feed not exists in database. Written.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Feed exists in database.");
        mongoClient.close();
        }
```

But in this way, I'm adding just new documents without updating.
*(As I understand, it's good, when cluster will check itself and delete without me older documents during **overflow "document size"**)*

When I'm trying to update older documents via adding check in else condition:

```
  // search feed
        Document found = database.getCollection("rss_feed").find(new Document("title", title)
                .append("url", url)
                .append("img", img)
                .append("price", price)).first();
        if (found == null) {
            collection.insertOne(new Document("title", title)
                    .append("url", url)
                    .append("img", img)
                    .append("price", price));
                     mongoClient.close();
        System.out.println("Feed not exists in database. Written.");
        } else {
            collection.updateOne(eq(found), new Document("title", title)
                    .append("url", url)
                    .append("img", img)
                    .append("price", price));
                    mongoClient.close();
            System.out.println("Feed exists in database. Updated");
        mongoClient.close();
        }
```

I'm getting:

```
WARNING: Unsupported option 'retrywrites' in the connection string
```

[image]

---

**Update:**

If I write `else if`condition with `count` method to check number of documents:

```
else if(collection.count() > 36) {
            collection.updateOne(found, new Document("updated title", title)
                    .append("updated url", url)
                    .append("updated img", img)
                    .append("updated price", price));
            System.out.println("Feed completely updated in database.");
```

then `else if` will be skipped:

```
Feed already exists in database.
Feed already exists in database.
Feed already exists in database.
Feed already exists in database.
Feed already exists in database.
```

Does anyone know how to write check documents to update them, if they're existing ?

Comment: Dont worry about the retryWrites warning. It can be ignored. Better remove from connection string. What about update part ? I'm not sure what exactly are you updating. It looks same  as insert/find. Do you have more code ?

Comment: @Veeram, thank you for check my answer here. I'm trying to find a method how to  update/delete my documents, if they're already existing and requiring update. For example, I have 36 documents with info, so my parser check it and trying to update them on new documents.

Comment: You are welcome. Still not clear. Did you try updating to different value ? Right now it is not going to update anything as nothing has changed from last document.  Also, you cant pass `found` directly to `Filters.eq`. Try `collection.updateOne(found, new Document("title", "update title") );`. This should show up in db.

Comment: @Veeram, this variant doesn't help me, unfortunately (nothing happens). I also update my question with additional attempt to realize updating number of documents more than fixed quantity.

Comment: Can you try `collection.replaceOne(found, new Document("title", "update title") );` ?

Comment: @Veeram yes, method `replaceOne` that exactly what I need,  thanks. Trying to implement by the same principle - check fixed quantity and then replacing `} else if(collection.count() > 36) { collection.replaceOne(found, new Document("updated title", title) .append("updated url", url) .append("updated img", img) .append("updated price", price)); System.out.println("Feed updated in database.");`. Still creating new documents without replacing. Adding in condition `else if(found.size() > 36)` just check size of collection not quantity documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways how to realize it:

1. [Using capped collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/).

> Capped collections automatically remove the oldest documents in the
>   collection without requiring scripts or explicit remove operations.

2. Using [replaceOne()](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/javadoc/?com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#replaceOne-org.bson.conversions.Bson-TDocument-) method.

> To replace a document, pass a new document to the replaceOne method.

3. Using [updateOne](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/javadoc/?com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#updateOne-org.bson.conversions.Bson-org.bson.conversions.Bson-)/[updateMany](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/javadoc/?com/mongodb/async/client/MongoCollection.html#updateMany-org.bson.conversions.Bson-org.bson.conversions.Bson-) methods. 
   In my case, I needed just to update several fields, so I wrote like:

   collection.updateOne(eq("_id", user_id), new Document("$set", new Document("View links", "On")));

> In some cases where you may need to update many fields in a document, it may be more efficient to replace the document.

Answer (score 1):

The `retryWrites` connection parameter was added in MongoDb 3.6 according to [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/core/retryable-writes/index.html). As you said yourself, you are using version 3.4, hence the warning.

Somewhere in your code you probably have a connection string that looks similar to this: `mongodb://db1.example.net:27017?retryWrites=true`. You either need to upgrade to a version >= 3.6 or remove the `retryWrites` parameter from the connection string in order to get rid of the warning.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question, Yannik. U're right that I need to avoid  `retryWrites`. But it's difenetly weird, because as mentioned mongodb company, I'm need to use `retryWrites` parameter in both variants.:
`3.4` - `mongodb://admin:<PASSWORD>@cluster0-shard-00-00-ox90k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-ox90k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-ox90k.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true`
and `3.6` - `mongodb+srv://admin:<PASSWORD>@cluster0-ox90k.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true`

Comment: But in both variants I can't update correctly even via avoiding the error

Comment: Sorry, I thought the problem was the warning. What do you mean when you say you "can't update correctly"? Do you get an actual error? Or is the update just not reflected in the database?

Comment: Nothing wrong, this answer also is helpful. :) This error was really because of `retryWrites` connection parameter.